# iOS admob stick to the bottom of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

I'm developing a new app and I'm using `initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait`but as default it stickes add to top. How can  I make it to stcick ads to bottom of screen? Thanks!

```
 bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
        bannerView_.adUnitID = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
        [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
        [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the frame below such that it always show ad at bottom on all iOS devices:

```
bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2.0 - bannerView_.frame.size.width/2.0
                              , screenHeight - bannerView_.frame.size.height
                              ,bannerView_.frame.size.width
                              ,bannerView_.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
bannerView_.center = CGPoint(x: bannerView_.center.x, y: view.bounds.size.height - bannerView_.frame.size.height / 2)
```

This correctly positions the ad on the bottom for me. It also works for all iphones/ipads on simulator. However, this code is in swift. I think the code is similar, if not the same, in objective C.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, the following initialization sets the banner to the bottom of the screen:

```
bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, self.view.frame.size.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to play with autoSizing ? Try setting to bottom, left, right and flexible width. I did this to make some of my views alway stick to bottom and it adjusts itself for 4" retina too if initially designed for 3.5" (retina).